# Expression to check if a given string exist in a output of a script task in ADF

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory, script-task

I get following result from my script task, How should I build expression to check if the result contains 'exceed'

{
"resultSetCount": 1,
"recordsAffected": 0,
"resultSets": [
{
"rowCount": 2,
"rows": [
{
"status": "exceed"
},
{
"status": "pass"
}
]
}
],

Answer (score 0):

You could just the [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#contains) function in the Azure Data Factory expression language.  In this example, I have used a parameter to hold the string value as I can't easily reproduce your script, but it should work for your example:

```
@contains(pipeline().parameters.pInput, 'exceed')
```

`contains` returns a boolean value so I am assigning it in a Set Variable activity just as an example:

[image: My results]

This is obviously a bit of a blunt instrument and using string methods rather than working with the json methods.  If you wanted to, you could loop through each row with a For Each activity but it hardly seems worth it.  Set the `items` of a For Each activity to something like this to loop through each row:

```
@json(pipeline().parameters.pInput).resultSets[0].rows
```

Comment: Any update on this?